# Comparison of looping, vectorization and parallel computing

Tags: r, loops, parallel-processing, vectorization

I created a list of datasets:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
library(stringr)
set.seed(42)  # Set seed for reproducibility

# Define the specified sequences and their corresponding weights
specified_sequences <- c("ABCD", "EFGH", "IJKL", "MNOP", "QRST", "UVWX", "YZAB")
specified_weights <- sample(100:200, length(specified_sequences), replace = TRUE)

# Define the remaining sequences
remaining_letters <- sample(LETTERS, 12)  # Choose 12 random letters
remaining_sequences <- combn(remaining_letters, 4, FUN = paste0, collapse = "")
remaining_weights <- sample(0:15, length(remaining_sequences), replace = TRUE)

# Combine the sequences and weights
all_sequences <- c(specified_sequences, remaining_sequences)
all_weights <- c(specified_weights, remaining_weights)

# Function to generate a random four-letter sequence with weights
generate_random_sequence <- function() {
  sample(all_sequences, 1, replace = TRUE, prob = all_weights)
}

# Function to generate a random four-letter sequence with weights
generate_random_sequence_modified <- function() {
  sample(all_sequences, 1, replace = TRUE, prob = all_weights)
}


# Create an empty list to store the datasets
dataset_list <- list()
nrow<-10^5

# Iterate over the years from 2011 to 2022
for (year in 2011:2022) {
  # Generate the vector based on the year
  if (year < 2023) {
    vector <- replicate(nrow, generate_random_sequence())
  } else {
    vector <- replicate(nrow, generate_random_sequence_modified())
  }
  
  # Create a random data frame for the year
  dataset <- data.frame(
    Age = rnorm(nrow, mean = 40, sd = 13),
    Gender = sample(c("Male", "Female"), nrow, replace = TRUE),
    Year = rep(year, nrow),
    vector = vector
  )
  
  # Add the dataset to the list
  dataset_list[[as.character(year)]] <- dataset
}
```

I want to perform the same data management on all datasets. A dozen data sets (one per year)

I computed the data management using loop

```
dataset_list_new<-list()

for (i in seq_along(dataset_list)) {
  
  cas_temp<-as.data.table(dataset_list[[i]])
  cas_temp[, new_var := as.integer(str_detect(vector, "ABCD|EFGH|IJKL"))]
  cas_temp <- cas_temp[, .(Age, Gender, Year, vector, new_var)]
  dataset_list_new[[i]]<-cas_temp
}
```

And `Parallelization`

```
# Set the number of parallel workers
num_cores <- 8  # Adjust this according to the number of available cores

# Initialize parallel backend
cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# Initialize an empty list to store the results
dataset_list_new2 <- vector("list", length = length(dataset_list_new))

# Parallel loop over indices of dataset_list_new
dataset_list_new2 <- foreach(i = seq_along(dataset_list_new), .combine = "list") %dopar% {
  library(data.table)
  library(tidyverse)
  cas_temp<-as.data.table(dataset_list[[i]])
  cas_temp[, new_var := as.integer(str_detect(vector, "ABCD|EFGH|IJKL"))]
  cas_temp <- cas_temp[, .(Age, Gender, Year, vector, new_var)]

  # Return the processed data.table
  return(cas_temp)
}
```

I have seen that the loop is more efficient (faster) than the parallel computing.

I wonder if in this particular case the loop is more efficient (because there are not many elements in the list) or if the parallelization was not well computed.

Or can the vectorization be better in this case? If so, can someone help me write code to vectorize this process?

Here are the characteristics of my computer:

```
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1065G7 CPU @ 1.30GHz   1.50 GHz
RAM: 32,0 Go (31,7 Go utilisable)
OS: Windows 64 bit
```

Comment: One comment: `library(tidyverse)` is an expensive operation. It loads or attaches around 50 packages, and it seems like you're doing it to run one function, `str_detect`. You could simplify greatly by only loading `stringr`, (or `stringi`), or better yet skip it entirely and use `grepl` from `base`.

Comment: And, I haven't run your code to look at your data to be sure, but it seems like your `vector` has 4-character sequences, in which case you are looking for **whole-string** exact matches, not matches within a larger string. If that's the case then `new_var := as.integer(any(c("ABCD", "EFGH", "IJKL") %in% vector))` will be **much** faster on large data.

Comment: And generally, parallel computing adds quite a bit of overhead. If the tasks are small, then the overhead of distributing the work to different threads and compiling the results may not be worth it. Running 25 medium tasks in parallel will likely be much more efficient than running 100 tiny tasks in parallel, even if the medium tasks are more than 4x larger than the tiny tasks.